# Is it currently possible to use pseudo tty with Core 3.1 on linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, pty

I am working on open-source programs to control Amateur radio via serial ports.  However, since serial ports are an exclusive resource only one application can use it at a time, but there is many applications that want to talk to the radio.  I am writing an application that pretends to be a radio so the client can talk to it.  Under the covers via SignalR sends and receives radio information via HamBus which the repo is on GitHub if you are interested.

So what I need is for the ham app that wants to talk to a radio via rs-232 to talk to my app via ptys instead.

On Windows, I use virtual COM ports and it seems like I can use PTY for the same purpose.

Is this possible?  Can I do it with C# and .NET Core?

Comment: Have you run `man 7 pty`?

Comment: Of course.  What I am asking is can it be done with Net Core 3.1.  If I remember my Linux it is fairly easy with C/C++, but I don't know if MSIL can access the ioctl.